# find: missing argument to '-exec'

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

this is my first post, as I am completely new to the programming world. Basically I'm taking a UNIX class and I have an assignment asking me to check the size of regular files in my home directory for file sizes greater or equal to 1KB, then back them up to a compressed file. I have to use extension .bak for the compressed file, and then clean them out. I have this so far:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1k -exec gzip -k -S.bak'{}'\;-exec cp'lab4.bak'/IFT383ss16/Labs/ \;   
find: paths must precede expression  
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

Trying to see if I can get a little help here maybe some suggestions?

Comment: Please note that `{}` must be a separate argument. It cannot be concatenated with other text.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you're being miserly with space characters.

You need a space before the `{}`, and both before and after the `\;` and after the `cp` and `'lab4.bak'`. You don't need single-quotes around the `{}` either.

The second `-exec ...` should probably be `-exec cp {}.bak /IFT383ss16/Labs/ \;`

Try this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1k \
    -exec gzip -k -S.bak {} \; \
    -exec cp {}.bak /IFT383ss16/Labs/ \;
```

That could all be on one-line.  I've used `\`s at the end of the first two lines to make it more readable (the shell will read lines with a `\` as the last non-space character as being continued on the next line).  It works the same on one line if you remove the end-of-line `\`s and join the lines yourself.

BTW, do you want to copy the .bak files or move them?  Maybe use `mv` instead of `cp`.